# There are a lot of piano-keyboards, is there any violin-mouse?

Tags: computer, mouse, piano

Keyboard on personal computer is ideal for emulation piano and making a digital organ.

What about mouse?

Comment: Sounds like a great open-source VSTi project. Straightforward application of Waveguide and Karplus-Strong. (modeling the bow, strings, and body)

Comment: + Trackpad theremin!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues to solve, but it is doable. I wrote a Java theremin. Available to try out if you have Java 8 running. Consider this a beta test version--please write back if you have suggestions! Contact info is on website. http://adonax.com/main/musicapps.htm

Main issues that I've come across:

- latency
- smoothness -- easy for there to be "zippering" and other problems between the transfer of info from GUI/mouse to audio application
- range -- getting a good trade-off between pitch range and accuracy of pitch is a problem
- vibrato is tricky to solve as the motion used for it should be orthogonal to movements used for pitch

All of these have been confronted in the theremin implementation I wrote. Successfully? TBD.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Serenade III from the Native Instruments Reaktor User Library (website).

It is "demoable" in Reaktor Player. It's a patch ("ensemble") for Reaktor.